# How can we establish the existence of electromagnetic waves on our own?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

In the realm of scientific inquiry, it becomes crucial to substantiate the existence of phenomena before considering their properties and applications. In the case of electromagnetic waves, the question arises as to how we can ascertain their existence. Electromagnetic waves are a fundamental component of the electromagnetic spectrum, encompassing various types such as radio waves, microwaves, infrared, visible light, ultraviolet, X-rays, and gamma rays. To establish the existence of these waves, scientists have conducted extensive experiments and observations over the course of history. Through careful experimentation, they have been able to detect and measure electromagnetic waves in different ways, such as through the use of antennas, detectors, and specialized instruments.

My question is how have scientists verified the existence of electromagnetic waves in the first place? Can we be able to do the same and conduct our own research in exploring and finding the properties of electromagnetic waves with and without current technology?

Comment: Does your cell phone work?

Comment: Hertz's original experiments did not satisfy modern safety standards. Much safer with modern tech. Similar experiments using a NanoVNA are pretty easy.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "on your own". Do you have to establish the existence of iron by finding iron ore and by smelting your own primitive tools from it or are you happy with buying a piece of steel in the home improvement store or the kitchen aisle of your grocery store? So how far back do you want to go with electromagnetism? All the way to Faraday or even Volta or are you happy with building your own AM radio and transmitter from electronic components for a few bucks?

Comment: You can demonstrate infrared radiation in the way it was originally discovered by Herschel.  It is a spectacularly simple and elegant experiment.

Comment: Look at a light bulb.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "establish". You can establish the existence of light by looking at it, or radio waves by turning on a radio. But establishing that light or radio waves are electromagnetic takes more. Maybe this will help? [How to Detect Electromagnetic Waves | Physics with Professor Matt Anderson | M25-03](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcPpDWA9zw0)

Comment: You might want to see the playlist of lectures for this video. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMXAf0aPgIuWgOnRiKcs92YZm8xD72Hrw